# last element in while loop php

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mails");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $mymail= $row['mail']. ",";
    echo $mymail;
}
```

I have after every row comma (,) but I don't want (,) after last row. How could I  do this?

Comment: These types of questions have been answered numerous times already on StackOverflow. Please [learn how to use the search function](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+last+comma+loop).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [join](https://php.net/join) function:

```
$mails = array();
$result = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM mails");
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $mails[] = $row['mail']; // Store E-Mail adresses in an array
}
$commaSeparatedMails = join(',', $mails); // Connect all array parts using a comma
echo $commaSeparatedMails;
```

Comment: I second that. I would've suggested `implode()`. I've never heard of  the `join()` function. Is there any difference in performance between these 2 functions?

Comment: @IonutTatu As the provided link to the docs state, it's just an alias to `implode()`. However, other languages (eg. .NET and JS) often call it `join` - so for consistency reason I always just remembered `join()` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

rtrim(yourstring,","), this function will remove right comma.

Comment: Which means will remove the comma from all entries, right?